# Everything is a flow?

Tags: language-agnostic

Some of my recent web projects that I worked on, use a flow engine as the central abstraction in the presentation and/or (more or less the) business layer. Reflecting on my experiences, I can honestly say that I am not a fan of the flow-centric approach. On the contrary even. I see the same symptoms pop up in projects that use flows as central abstraction.

- **Everything is a flow.** You don't just start an application, no, you "enter the main flow" even if it is just to show a menu with a huge dispatcher behind it. I am not against flows as such. Some use cases keep popping up everywhere and need to be included at various points in other use cases (LookupCustomer, ...), but for flow-centric people *everything* is a flow, even things that are... not flows.
- **Fragmentation.** Flow-based applications tend to have many pieces of logic (actions, commands, fragments of code to prepare the view...) dispersed throughout the code. Mapping in and out of these actions adds overhead, is tedious and bloats the code. Although it is easy to follow the abstract flow, actually figuring out what is happening inside these little (or big) chunks of code is another thing. While every style of application allows people to write bad and inconsistent code, flow-centric applications make it particularly easy to do so.
- **Config files.** Most applications use some XML format to declare flows and actions that accompany state changes. The language in which the application is written (say Java, C#, Ruby, ...) is probably far more richer and expressive than the XML format ever will be. Why bother?
- **Flows break encapsulation.** If you give me a component that has a certain embedded flow logic, then the flow should be part of the component, and should not be an external abstraction. In other words: the flow is part of the component and the component is self-contained. It is a detail. Sure, it can be parameterized and stuff, but a component should "just work". People writing a Swing, GWT, or whatever fat or rich interface application, don't bother with explicit flow abstractions. Why should my web application have one? Give me the flow diagram of GMail.
- (Edit) **Flows are procedural.** If you look at "rich" patterns like MVC with events and everything, flows really pale in comparison. You *are* using an modern and expressive language to implement your application, right? So you *can* do better than the rigid "do this, then that, and that, and ..." way from the time when punchcards and assembler were in fashion.

Examples of frameworks that promote flow-centric development are Struts, BTT, Spring Webflow, and JSF. I've also come across homegrown flow engines built on top of ordinary servlets.

This is also an interesting article: http://chillenious.wordpress.com/2006/07/16/on-page-navigation/

Do you (still) think a flow-centric approach for (the front-end of) a web-application is a good idea?

Comment: I think it would help if you gave a more concrete definition of "flow" or at least link to a resource where those of us with no exposure to flow-centric design can get a feel for it. Is this what you're talking about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming ?

Comment: Don't look to far. Things like Struts and Spring Webflow also qualify as being flow-centric.

Comment: I think by "flow" he means the routings or actions that MVC frameworks use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, flows seem to be an unnecessarily enterprisey approach to what should be a relatively simple problem: we would like to ensure that users take one of several particular paths through our application. What's more instructive and insightful is to examine *why* we need this path to occur. Is it because...

- ... we don't want them to interact with our application except in rigidly predefined ways? Then we've limited the utility of our application, and we make our application much harder to change and use.
- ... we're worried about the ability of our application to handle unexpected input or deal with states we haven't anticipated if people stray off the beaten path? Then that says a lot about our technical choices for a validation framework.
- ... we can't envision a scenario other than the predefined ones under which someone would use the site? Then we are implicitly assuming that only we know how best to use it; we limit the ability of the user to control their interaction.

Notice how each of these underscores an issue intrinsic to the application's development and team members, and one that's not the fault of a user. So I support your general premise that flow-based approaches tend to have a number of issues.

The primary problem is that **flows unnecessarily increase brittleness that is already better abstracted by other mechanisms.** For example, to achieve a rule like "you need to fill out your order form before you confirm checkout", don't make a workflow; have a better `CustomerOrder` model that knows when it doesn't have all the information necessary to allow an `OrderConfirmation`. If you try to skip ahead, your model and controller should take care of failing validation on the next `POST`.

Essentially, flows extract out disparate fragments of each participating controller and collect them into a new "flow controller" that's specific to each flow. That's not necessarily a bad idea, but it suggests that the original controllers may have been taking on too much responsibility to begin with if that sort of path was so easy to define separately. For example, if you previously had `OrderConfirmation`, `CustomerOrder`, and `OrderCheckout` controllers, and you're thinking about an `Order` flow to link all three together, **what you should probably be thinking about is an `Order` controller instead**.

Comment: Flows are not about "ensuring a path", "rigidly predefining", "handling unexpected input" or "achieving a rule" - that's what validation frameworks and business rules are for. Flows simply define (or configure) explicitly how your application works, which is something you do implicitly anyway in your controllers and the accompanying controller configuration code.

Comment: My point is that the configuration is better left to things we've already invented which are more effective and less complex (convention over configuration tends to have advantages). Also, I've noticed that practical implementation of flows (e.g. Spring WebFlow) tend to be non-REST-ful. That's not to say you can't write RESTful flows, but the frameworks don't seem to encourage this.

Answer (score 1):

I think defining flows is useful in a web application. In answer to your main points:

> Everything is a Flow.

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with that, it's just a name to give something. A flow can be short or long - I agree it's a bit weird that there is a "main" flow that starts everything but it doesn't really cause any problems in practice.

> Fragmentation

You have some valid points here, although I get the feeling that the greatest contributor to this is the design of the DSL. For example, Spring WebFlow v2 is a vast improvement over SWF v1 in terms of readability and understandability.

> Config files

I strongly disagree with this point. I feel that xml **is** the best way to express this code. If you think about it -  managing controllers, views, state changes and actions is really just "configuration" rather than "code". And xml (in my opinion) is the best way to express configuration. Just think about the word "Controller". All a controller does is direct and configure things - call services, return views and models etc. There is no need for any richness or expressiveness of Java to define what is basically just configuration of your web application.

> Flows break encapsulation

GMail could expressed in a series of flows. Think about the number of steps it takes to compose and send an email. Flows really just define the wiring of how the application works - sure you could have a number of components that interact with each other, but the way that you configure them to work together is essentially the flow you have defined in your application. Making this flow explicit in a separate DSL seems like a good idea to me, as fundamentally it **is** separate.

Answer (score 1):

The first question that should be answered is whether a flow framework is really the best tool for your specific web application.  I'm a fan of Spring Web Flow, myself, but I'll only use it if my web app can easily be broken down into flows, and if navigation should be tightly controlled.  If the navigation is very loose, where you can get to almost any page from any other page, then SWF isn't the right tool for the job.

As you mention, there are other drawbacks to flow frameworks.  They usually aren't RESTful, and thus not bookmarkable.  If that conflicts with what you want for your application, then SWF probably isn't for you.

That said, SWF, and some of the other flow frameworks, offer some features that few other web frameworks deliver.  This includes complete solutions for double-submit issues and browser back button and history handling.  SWF's implementation of these features lends some additional security.  Since the flow execution IDs for each page change as the application is used, you get immunity to forced browsing and some protection against cross-site request forgery.

The concept of flows is quite nice, in my opinion, since flows tend to mirror use cases.  Scoping data to a flow or a conversation removes the responsibility for its cleanup from the developer, which I think is a very good thing.  It's like the difference between manual memory management and garbage collection.  Not only does it make less work for me, but it eliminates the possibility of introducing bugs should I forget to cleanup attributes.  One thing I hated about Struts was that I needed to duplicate my cleanup code in several actions to ensure correctness.  It's much easier just to scope the data to the use case.

Flows also present a context for related actions and views.  If I look at a struts-config or faces-config file, I can see all kinds of navigation rules or action mappings, but there is no immediate context for me to mentally group related items together.  I have to manually trace through the configuration, and even then sometimes I get stuck.  With Struts, I need to look at the specific web pages in order to figure out which actions can be invoked from a view.

With SWF, I can clearly see all the actions, views, and models related to a flow.  With Eclipse plugins, I can see this as a state diagram.  Even if you're not using eclipse, it's very easy to translate a flow definition to a state diagram.  These diagrams are useful for myself, my project manager, and pretty much anyone who wants to understand the high-level of how a use case is performed.  In short, chunking related things together allows for easier understanding, and a shallower learning curve.  That's one reason why OOP is so popular.  With web apps, the idea of chunking these elements together to form a use case just feels natural.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything is a flow

Everything really is a flow. Computer programs had always been a flow and will always be a flow containing of theese processes:

**input -> process -> output**

The MVC design pattern in fact corresponds with this..

**controller -> model -> view**

> Fragmentation

You're right. But I think this "issue" might be reduced by a good suppport in IDEs.

> Config files

There's no doubt xml is the best way to express configuration.

> Flows break encapsulation

I would disagree with this. You can make black boxes using flows and then use these black boxes in another flows.

Comment: Wow... I think there's a lot of doubt that XML is the best way to express configuration. In some environments, it's the path of least resistance, but it's neither as readable as YAML nor as clear as code.

Comment: MVC is not a good example to make your point I think. As you say, every program has data and control flow, but MVC itself is never represented as a "flow-centric" pattern. Good MVC is a set of interacting objects with separate responsiblities that must cooperate, but there is no overarching flow concept. In MVC, there is usually no 'start' or 'end'.

Comment: That's right. I ment that that even in MVC, there must be theese 3 main processes present and that they could be "mapped" to model, view and controller as written above.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, web apps are best developed as independent modules rather than modules that are "bound by flow".

Since most web apps today are ajaxy apps, having independent modules on the page helps a lot.

Configurations can be handled by XML or JSON files.

Answer (score 0):

Web 2.0 presents a serious challenge to the notion that "everything is a flow".   And when the presentation tier is fully transposed to the client layer, we'll be back on the solid, and familiar (from GUIs of yore) ground of event based processing.

Answer (score 0):

Flows arise because of the inherit mismatch between traditional application interaction and the way web applications actually work. Flows are merely a convenient way to describe what would be more traditionally modeled as a series of GUI dialogs (think wizard) in a way that is compatible with the way in which web pages are delivered and interacted with. Imagine if you will that you were writing a traditional program, but every time the user ran the program you could only display a single dialog box, and when the user clicked "Ok" (or "Cancel", or "Next", or "Previous") your program would terminate. In that situation, how would you go about modeling the expected behavior of the program (to further complicate matters, assume many users are running the program at different times)? I think you would find you would rather quickly arrive at something similar to flows.

I think perhaps what you're really asking is, "Why are most flow frameworks so easy to abuse?", which naturally leads to the followup question "What can be done to fix that?".